# Domino Designer can't "TeamDevelopment > Sync with On-Disk Project"

Tags: java, database, replication, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I am Using the Domino Designer 9.0, FP 8 and I can't sync my Gitrepositry with my Java Code on my Database. 
Sometimes it works just fine, but most of the time the Designer shows me the Sync Conflict window. For my files I always select Use "On-Disk Project Version". The Window closes and opens up again.

When I open a file which should have changed,edit and save it, the "Sync Conflict" window opens up again. So i assume the designer knows the different files but can't write into my database(?).

What I have tried to fix to problem so far:
-Deleting local replica and create a new local replica
-Remove database from Designer and reassociate the git with the database
-changing the properties of the Java files (Prohibit reffresh or replace to modify)
-rebuild, refresh etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Swiper from OpenNTF [link](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Swiper)
After install plug-in use toolbar buttons, it's work for me.